# Is there anyway to configure an ssh server in Memu play emulator?

Tags: c#, ssh, android-emulator, scp, openssh

Hello every body I wanna run the memu play macro commands from an external desktop app , and to do that I need either to execute the commands in a secure shell (ssh) or to transfer the .scp file  containing the commands to Memu play via (ssh) again , after some researches I found this nugget package **Renci.SshNet**  that permit me to create a ssh client but I don't know how to configure the server part in Memu play.

I am using windows and the desktop app is built using c#

```
                var auth1 = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password);

                //the username and the password shoud be configured in the server part 

                var auth2 = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod("username");                
                ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo("host", "user", auth1, auth2);               
                var sshClient = new SshClient(conInfo);
                sshClient.Connect();
                var cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("ls");
                var r = cmd.Execute();
```